# Error of casting

Tags: javascript, html

Can someone tell me how to resolve this error:

[Image 1](http://s11.postimg.org/qkwmjivsh/Photo.png)

I tried, but does not work in browsers ...

[Image 2](http://s23.postimg.org/ep4saj6ll/Photo2.png)

Comment: Your question should be complete and not rely on links for essential content. Even considering the linked content, it's not clear what you're asking. It seems that your question is actually about your IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why can't you do this :

```
var d = document.getElementById("d1"); 

d.setAttribute("value", "newValue");
```